# SQL length of changed data

Tags: sql, sql-server, sorting, sql-server-2008

I have a table:

```
ID   |     date     |   Location A   |   Location B
1234    2018-06-16        Chicago          Chicago
1234    2018-06-15        Chicago          Chicago
1234    2018-06-14        Chicago          Chicago
1234    2018-06-13        Chicago          Florida
1234    2018-06-12        Baltimore        Florida
1234    2018-06-11        California       Florida
1234    2018-06-10        California       Florida
4444    2018-06-16        Utah             Utah
4444    2018-06-15        Utah             Utah
4444    2018-06-14        Utah             Utah
4444    2018-06-13        Chicago          Utah
4444    2018-06-12        Baltimore        Utah
4444    2018-06-11        California       Florida
4444    2018-06-10        California       Florida
6214    2018-06-16        Baltimore        Baltimore
6214    2018-06-15        Baltimore        Baltimore
6214    2018-06-14        Baltimore        Baltimore
6214    2018-06-13        Baltimore        Florida
6214    2018-06-12        Baltimore        Florida
6214    2018-06-11        Baltimore        Florida
```

My goal is to have a new column that indicates the number of days since location A and Location B have been matching But ONLY if they did NOT match previously AND Location B was the same as the match before or on the same day location A was changed to the match AND the Date is the latest Date.

The above table would then look like the following

```
ID   |     date     |   Location A   |   Location B | Days Matched
1234    2018-06-16        Chicago          Chicago        3
4444    2018-06-16        Utah             Utah           3
```

ID 6214 will not be in the table because Location A was already the match before Location B was for more than 1 Day.

Comment: Why Baltimore-Baltimore and Baltimore-Florida not in the output? Your requirements are not clear to me. Have you tried looking at LAG?

Comment: use a WITH to make various CTE's which you can ad ROW_NUMBER too, that can give you rows that match, the rows that were different.  I don't understand your second condition 'AND Location B was the same as the match before or on the same day location A was changed to the match ' so I'm not going to attempt it yet (what is 'The Match')

Comment: Basically Location B is a suggestion and Location A is the real current location I want to know how many days ago the suggestion was taken, but only if the suggestion was made. Baltimore - Baltimore does not show up because the Location A was already Baltimore before Location B (The suggestion) was made.

Comment: sorry did not mention that the first date should be today's date.

Answer (score 0):

Best Try I Could Give Without a Fiddle:

- Gets the Most Recent Record For Each ID as Inner Query
- Inner Inner Query Has Highest Not Matched Date
- Outer Query Pulls a Count Greater Than the Not Matched Date.  If Not Matched Date Is Null, Then It Grabs All the Records

Here's The Query

```
SELECT A.ID, A.DATE, A.LOCATIONA, A.LOCATIONB,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE V WHERE A.ID=V.ID AND (A.NOTMATCHEDDATE IS NULL OR V.NOTMATCHEDDATE>A.NOTMATCHEDDATE) AS CNT
FROM
(
SELECT ID, DATE, LOCATIONA, LOCATIONB,
    (
       SELECT MIN(DATE) FROM TABLE U WHERE T.ID=U.ID AND U.LOCATIONA<>U.LOCATIONB)
    ) AS NOTMATCHEDDATE,
FROM TABLE T
WHERE LOCATIONA=LOCATIONB AND 
  NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM TABLE S WHERE S.ID=T.ID AND S.DATE>T.DATE)
) A
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't follow all the rules myself. In particular I still don't understand why you want 1234/Chicago when Chicago was never "suggested" previously. Here's a stab:

```
with x as (
    select *,
        row_number() over (partition by ID order by DT desc) as rn,
        first_value(LocationA) over (partition by ID order by DT desc) as fv,
        count(*) over (partition by ID, LocationB) as cntB,
        count(case when LocationA = LocationB then 1 end) over (partition by ID) as cntE
    from T
), y as (
    select * from x where cntB > cntE
)
select cntE from y
where rn = 1 and DT = cast(getdate() as date);
```

This is a little generic but my impression is that your sequence of locations and suggestions is constrained enough that it might work. Also I went ahead and used `first_value()` realizing that it might not be available to you.

Find some DDL over here: http://rextester.com/CRST10642

**EDIT**

This may be totally on the wrong track but here's another thought:

```
with x as (
    select *,
        row_number() over (partition by ID order by DT desc) as rn,
        first_value(LocationA) over (partition by ID order by DT desc) as fv,
        count(*) over (partition by ID, LocationB) as cntB,
        count(case when LocationA = LocationB then 1 end) over (partition by ID) as cntE
    from T
), y as (
    select *,
        max(case when LocationA = fv then rn end) over (partition by ID) as maxA,
        max(case when LocationB = fv then rn end) over (partition by ID) as maxB    
    from x
)
select * from y where rn = 1 and maxB + 1 >= maxA;
```

Comment: Because the suggestion (Location B) lags behind one day in the table. so technically that suggestion was made the same day that Location A was changed to Chicago